# Prove that there exists a unique partition of $\mathbb{N}$ into A and B so that neither of $A\oplus A$ and $B\oplus B$ has a prime.

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, contest-math, divisibility

> For any subset $S\subseteq \mathbb{N}, $ let $S\oplus S = \{a + b : a,b \in S , a\neq b\}$. Prove that there exists a unique partition of $\mathbb{N}$ into disjoint subsets A and B so that neither of $A\oplus A$ and $B\oplus B$ has a prime.

Clearly we can just let $A$ and $B$ be the set of even and odd positive integers respectively, but I'm not sure how to prove that these values are unique. But how would we prove that this partition is unique? I think it might be useful to first show that for such a partition, all the elements of $A\oplus A$ and $B\oplus B$ must be even integers greater than 2. If there were an odd integer in $A\oplus A$, A would have to contain both an odd integer and an even integer, but I don't see how to get a contradiction from here.

Comment: Remember $0\in\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Not everyone considers $0\in\mathbb{N}$. It is a matter of taste.

Comment: @AnneBauval Look at the precise definition of $\oplus$.

Comment: @user10354138 The OP considers  $2+0\notin A\oplus A$ hence $0\notin\Bbb N.$

Comment: Anyway, if it was $\mathbb{Z}^+$ instead of $\mathbb{N}$, then recall [Bertrand's postulate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_postulate).

Comment: Second that, Bertrand's plus induction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without loss of generality let $1\in A$. Since $1+2$ is a prime, we have $2\in B$. Suppose that we know already that $A$ contains all odd integers up to $2k-1$ and $B$ contains all even integers up to $2k$. By Bertrand's Postulate, there exists a prime between $2k+1$ and $4k+2$. This shows that $2k+1$ cannot lie in $B$ and therefore $2k+1\in A$. Now I think, one can finish by induction on $k$.

Comment: For small values of $k$, $2k+1$ could be the only prime between $2k-1$ and $4k-2$. For example, $7$ is the only prime between $5$ and $10$, and so that won't help to show that $7 \not\in B$. So, instead, consider primes between $2k+1$ and $4k+2$ in Bertrand's Postulate.

Comment: @GeoffreyTrang  Right, I will change that.